# Firebase Error: Credentials fetcher does not implement Google\Auth\UpdateMetadataInterface

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Please I'm trying to fetch data from firebase in PHP, and it's giving me this error

```
Uncaught RuntimeException: Credentials fetcher does not implement Google\Auth\UpdateMetadataInterface
```

this is my code:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;

$db = new FirestoreClient([
    'projectId' => 'firebase-db-name'
]);


$docRef = $db->collection('collection')->document('document');
$snapshot = $docRef->snapshot();

if ($snapshot->exists()) {
printf('Document data:' . PHP_EOL);
print_r($snapshot->data());
} else {
printf('Document %s does not exist!' . PHP_EOL, $snapshot->id());
}
```

please what i'm i doing wrong or what do i suppose to import into the code for it to work and stop giving me the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked for me

'project_Id' => 'firebase-db-name',

'keyFile' => json_decode(file_get_contents('./file.json'), true)

get KeyFile = Firebase Console/Project Settings/Service accounts/Firebase admin SDK/->  Generate new private key
then download it and past it with file.json

percent: 100% sussced

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue in a Laravel 7 project. I found a solution by activating Firestore [API](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=firestore.googleapis.com&pli=1). Maybe this solution will help you.

Comment: I enabled it. And also add the JSON service account file in the code but still facing this error.

"Credentials fetcher does not implement Google\Auth\UpdateMetadataInterface"